# Does using limit clause in pyspark reader always result in only 1 partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have noticed that the output to the following code `spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).schema(schema).load(path).limit(nrows).rdd.getNumPartitions()` is always 1 notwithstanding the argument `nrows`. Does using limit clause always result in only 1 partition?

[I haven't been able to find anything mentioned about such constraint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the background of this. But for this statement, the result will always be 1 as you tried to collect result.

```
>>> df3.limit(1000000).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 1000000
+- FileScan csv
```

But for `LimitExec` which is physical leaf node for limit operation. It has several implementation such as `GlobalLimitExec`, `LocalLimitExec`. For some implementations, it could use same partition num to parrellel fetch enough records, or pick subsets of partitions iteratively. Generally, you don't need to care how is doing.